# link_to with target blank with Rinku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I click on a link I would like to make it go to a new page. How would I add target: "_blank" using the Rinku gem? My code is below, which is from my view.

```
<p><%= Rinku.auto_link(win.description).html_safe %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<p><%= Rinku.auto_link(win.description, html: { target: '_blank' }).html_safe %></p>`

**Update:** Maybe you have an old version, try this:

`<p><%= Rinku.auto_link(win.description, target: '_blank' ).html_safe %></p>`

[documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link)

Comment: That threw an error. "wrong argument type Hash (expected Symbol)"

Comment: Didn't work. It says wrong argument type Hash (expected Symbol)

Answer (score 1):

The following work for me:

```
<p><%=Rinku.auto_link(win.description, :all, 'target="_blank"').html_safe %></p>
```

It is similar to Zishe's answer above, but by changing `target: '_blank'` to `'target="_blank"`, it avoids the "wrong argument type Hash (expected Symbol)" error to which Zach S was referring.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you added code formatting and explained specifically what is different/why that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><%=Rinku.auto_link(win.description, :all, "target='_blank'").html_safe %></p>
```

Rinku.auto_link takes 3 parameters

text: string,

mode: symbol,

link_attr: string

Pass all 3 parameters correctly and it works.
Refer docs: https://github.com/vmg/rinku

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when calling `html_safe`, the code above is vulnarable:

```
<%= Rinku.auto_link("<script>alert('hi')</script>", :all, 'target="_blank"').html_safe %>
```

You could see nice `Hi!` executed.

To avoid it, **you must** escape the content:

```
<%= Rinku.auto_link(h("<script>alert('hi')</script>"), :all, 'target="_blank"').html_safe %>
```

Now, you can see `<script>alert('hi')</script>` as expected.